# ASP.NET Core + IIS + SSL

Tags: ssl, iis, asp.net-core

If I would like to use https in an ASP.NET Core application running IIS as a reverse proxy, do I need to configure the SSL cert in IIS or ASP.NET Core or both?

My plan was to install the cert on IIS. Is this enough?

Answer (score 3):

Install cert on IIS is enough, as current implementation of IIS (ASP.NET Core Module) [forwards client certificates to application](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/27) anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that should be correct - IIS handles SSL, so the back plane to ASP.NET Core can be unsecured.

This post gives a good explanation of how to set it up. It applies to RC2 but should be essentially unchanged for RTM.

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/06/Publishing-and-Running-ASPNET-Core-Applications-with-IIS