# ASP.Net Core 2.0 IIS Express SSL Client Certificate Prompt on Static Files

Tags: ssl, https, asp.net-core-2.0, iis-express, client-certificates

**Environment/Frameworks:**
Windows7
asp.net core 2.0 application running in IIS Express in VS2017
IE11, Edge, Chrome

**Background:**
I have and Asp.net Core 2.0 MVC application that I want to run in such a way that I get prompted to pick a client certificate in order to access the application.  In my local computer for testing purposes, I have created a sample fake self-signed certificate as per this article http://dcdevs.blogspot.com/2017/06/iis-express-client-certificates.html, and I have configured my asp.net core 2 application in VS2017 by going to project Properties -> Degub Tab, and checking Enable SSL, then copying the generated URL to the App URL text box.

On the Startup.cs or Program.cs I have NOT added any settings to required SSL, which means to my understanding that IIS Express is serving as proxy to require https then forwarding the requests to Kestrel in a regular http request as per this post [ASP.NET Core + IIS + SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38128483/asp-net-core-iis-ssl)

All in all, when I run the application I get prompted to select a certificate, then I am able to read the certificate and extract information out of it inside a controller. The application comes up, and I can see everything on the Home page with its banner image, but I cannot see the images that are retrieved from a javascript file and then placed on the page with DOM manipulation. This happens in IE11, and Edge, but Chrome just works fine.

**Problem:**
When I load a page I get prompted to select a certificate and then the page opens, but any javascript that make subsequent requests to load images (static files) hosted on the same application under wwwroot also gets prompted. When I hit F12 and monitor the network calls, this request to static files appear as Aborted in EI11 and Pending in Edge. If I open a new tab and copy the image url, I get prompted for a certificate the first time. If I navigate to different links on the application which invoke other controller's actions the pages just display fine, the main banner image of the site still displays fine.  It is just the calls to static files (e.g. images) that cause the prompt for certificate to appear again. As I described above I don't have this problems when I run the application in Chrome.